# How to find unique value in a DataFrame column type of object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

```
input_data = [np.array(['chicken', 'creamofchickensoup'], dtype=object), np.array(['stickscelery', 'Chicken', 'CreamofChickensoup', 'babycarrots', 'pepper'], dtype=object), np.array(['chicken', 'creamofchickensoup'], dtype=object)]
```

I want to find the unique values for this column 'input_data'. If pandas.unique() is used,  I received this `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

When `pd.Series(input_data).value_counts()` used, the result is

```
>>> pd.Series(input_data).value_counts()
[chicken, creamofchickensoup]                                       1
[stickscelery, Chicken, CreamofChickensoup, babycarrots, pepper]    1
[chicken, creamofchickensoup]                                       1
dtype: int64
```

The expected value for `[chicken, creamofchickensoup]` should be 2.

How to find unique value for a column dtype is object? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this with a `pandas.Series`

Comment: maybe try sorted `tuple` instead..? `pd.Series(input_data).apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the inner arrays with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and take a `set`:

```
from itertools import chain

set(chain.from_iterable(input_data))

{'Chicken',
 'CreamofChickensoup',
 'chicken',
 'creamofchickensoup',
 'stickscelery'}
```

---

To obtain the `value_counts`, you need to `explode` the column:

```
pd.Series(input_data).explode().value_counts()

creamofchickensoup    1
Chicken               1
chicken               1
CreamofChickensoup    1
stickscelery          1
dtype: int64
```